# Equal command between wget and cURL (with options)?

Tags: wget, curl

I usually use `wget` to download remote file, the command I use:

`wget --timeout=5 --tries=1 --referer=http://www.example.com 'http://www.example.com/abcdefg123.jpg' -O image.jpg`

As you can see, there are 3 options: `--timeout`, `--tries`, and `--referer`.

I wonder what is the proper / equal command in `cURL` that has similar options in `wget`?

Comment: I suggest reading `man curl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an *exact* equivalent to the last detail, but something like this might work:

```
curl -L --connect-timeout 5 --retry 1 --referer http://www.example.com -o image.jpg http://www.example.com/abcdefg123.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl --retry 1 --connect-timeout 5 -o image.jpg -e 'http://www.example.com' http://www.example.com/abcdefg123.jpg
```

There is also timeout option `-m` for the operation, depending on what you need.